# Multiple values in one entry

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a problem while setting my database.

The context: I have a company table that can have 0, 1 or multiples jobs. Jobs have its own table. I will need to join both table.

How can I "say" that a company has this, this and this job?

The only way I found is by creating a "job" value in the meta_key entry (of the company table) and declared the jobs in the meta_value entry but it seams not good (and will create difficulty to retrieve the jobs while joining).

Comment: please show your table and code

Comment: Select the company, then another query to select the job per company. Joins aren't always needed

Comment: Jobs will have a foreign key to a company, if a job can only relate to one company. I have no idea what these "meta" things are

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer but as a job can be in multiple companies, the answer of @juergen-d fit my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a many to many relation. It works like this

```
company table
-------------
id
name
other columns


jobs table
----------
id
name
other columns


company_jobs table
------------------
company_id
job_id
```

Comment: This is only valid when a job can have multiple companies. If a job has only one company, a simple jobs.company_id will suffice

Comment: I didn't said but yes, a job can have multiple companies. Thanks a lot @juergen-d !